# How to use addition correctly within exists conditional? CLIPS

Tags: syntax-error, exists, addition, clips

I am trying to check if there are any obstacles in front of the car. Let's say car is at location "2". My goal is to check if there are any obstacles at location "3".
  There might not be defined facts of obstacles that means there aren't any at       that particular location. I check that using **exists** conditional. But I get CLIPS syntax error **[PRNTUTIL2]** for this part **(+ ?location_car 1)** in rule **r6** . It works if I discard the addition. What alternative could I use, or am I just missing some syntax things?

```
  (deftemplate car
  (slot location)
)
(deftemplate obstacles
  (slot location) ; location of road segment
  (slot tlights) ; number of red traffic lights
  (slot cars) ; number of cars which have priority drive through
  (slot pedestrians) ; number of pedestrians crossing the road
  (slot spec_service) ; number of spec service vehicles passing by
)

(deffacts faktu-inicializavimas
 (car (location 0))
 (obstacles (location 9) (tlights 1) (cars 2) (pedestrians 5) (spec_service 2))
)

(defrule r6 "Drive to location"
  ?fact-id1 <- (car (location ?location_car))
  (or
    (exists (obstacles (location (+ ?location_car 1)) (tlights 0) (cars 0) (pedestrians 0) (spec_service 0)))
    (not
      (exists (obstacles (location (+ ?location_car 1)) ))
    )
  )
=>
 (printout t "Drive to location")
 (modify ?fact-id1 (location (+ ?location_car 2)))
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the return value constraint (the equal sign, =) to constrain a field to the return value of a function call.

```
(defrule r6 "Drive to location"
  ?fact-id1 <- (car (location ?location_car))
  (or
    (exists (obstacles (location =(+ ?location_car 1)) 
                       (tlights 0) 
                       (cars 0) 
                       (pedestrians 0) 
                       (spec_service 0)))
    (not
      (exists (obstacles (location =(+ ?location_car 1)) ))
    )
  )
=>
 (printout t "Drive to location")
 (modify ?fact-id1 (location (+ ?location_car 2)))
)
```